# Non-serializable value was detected in the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've been seeing this error while I log in and go to the dashboard.

it's showing this error
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `bugs.0`. Value: bug {name: "Crash on load", details: "Crash after 3 seconds", steps: "Open application and it will Crash", priority: 1, assigned: undefined, …}
Take a look at the reducer(s) handling this action type: bug/getBugs.

this is the reducer:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {retrieveBugs} from '../bugController'

const slice = createSlice({
    name:"bug",
    initialState:[{}],
    reducers:{
        getBugs:(state) => retrieveBugs(),
        
        createBugs: (state,actions) =>{
            const {name,details,steps,priority,assaigned,creator,version,time} = actions.payload;
            state.LoggedIn =true;
            state.admin = true;
        },
        updateBug:(state,actions) => {
            const {name,details,steps,priority,assaigned,creator,version,time} = actions.payload;
            state.LoggedIn =true;
            state.admin= true;
        
        },
        markComplete:(state,actions) => {
            const {name,details,steps,priority,assaigned,creator,version,time} = actions.payload;
            state.LoggedIn =true;
            state.admin= true;
        }
    }
})

export default slice.reducer;

export const {getBugs, createBugs, updateBug, markComplete} = slice.actions;
```

And here is the bugController

```
import bugModel from '../Models/bugModel'

export function retrieveBugs(){
    let data = [];

    data.push(new bugModel({
        name:"Crash on load",
        details: "Crash after 3 seconds",
        steps: "Open application and it will Crash",
        assaigned: "Al Amzad",
        creator: "John Doe",
        priority: 1,
        version: "V1.0",
        time: "1:45",
    }))
    
      data.push(new bugModel({
        name:"Wont load",
        details: "Application doesn't load",
        steps: "Open the Application it won't Load ",
        assaigned: "Al Amzad",
        creator: "John Doe",
        priority: 3,
        version: "V3.0",
        time: "23:45",
    }))

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    let sorted = data.sort((a,b) => {return a.priority - b.priority})

    return sorted;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Redux requires that you *only* put plain non-serializable JS objects, arrays, and primitives into state](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).

A `new bugModel` is going to be a class instance, and therefore not a plain serializable JS object.  So, RTK is specifically catching this mistake and warning you not to do that.

The fix is to switch to using plain data instead of classes.